# Why small sized struct improves performance over a large sized struct?

Tags: .net, performance, struct, clr

Many answer in SO and in the internet in general to "why should struct be small sized" refers to performance, but none explains **why**. Can anyone shed some light on it, please?

Comment: Because it is a valuetype and the value is copied when passed to or returned from methods, or assigned.

Comment: @leppie then it's about less memory copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struct is a value type and when it is for example passed to function - it's copied. So if struct has size 512 bits - all 512 bits will be copied. If you'll pass reference type - only 32/64 bits of reference to these 512 bits will be copied. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Next, reference type assignments copy the reference, whereas value type assignments copy the entire value. Therefore, assignments of large reference types are cheaper than assignments of large value types.

Comment: Sorry to split hairs here: Everything is passed by value in C# unless you explicitly pass by reference. When you pass a reference type the reference itself is copied. This is not the same thing as pass by reference in C#.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, agree, added more details to answer

Comment: @BrianRasmussen the quote talks about assignments, not argument passing.